# NodeJS | How to be logined after closing browser using passport and express?

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I use in my project **express** and **passport** for working with session and it works fine instead of one problem. When i close browser my session deserialized and this is fine, but i need to be logined after connecting again. Should i save information in cookies or use another package in npm? A little bit about my code:

```
app.use(session({
secret:'secret',
maxAge: new Date(Date.now() + 3600000),
httpOnly: true,
cookie: { path: '/', httpOnly: true, maxAge: null}, 
store: new MongoStore(
    {mongooseConnection:mongoose.connection},
    function(err){
        console.log(err || 'connect-mongodb setup ok');
    })
}));

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
```

As you can see i use a common **passport+express** program. Just give me any good tips for searching.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is change `cookie: { path: '/', httpOnly: true, maxAge: null}` to `cookie: { path: '/', httpOnly: true, maxAge: 36000000}`